# Parse Date Pattern

Tags: bash, date, gnu-coreutils

I'm trying to convert the Date into a specific format using awk and following are the commands that I've tried.

```
$ echo | awk -v Date=`date -d '2019-10-07'  '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'` '{print Date}'
2019-10-07T00:00:00
$ echo | awk -v Date=`date -d '2019-10-07T'  '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'` '{print Date}'
2019-10-07T01:00:00
$ echo | awk -v Date=`date -d '2019-10-07D'  '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'` '{print Date}'
2019-10-07T12:00:00
$ echo | awk -v Date=`date -d '2019-10-07S'  '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'` '{print Date}'
2019-10-07T02:00:00
$ echo | awk -v Date=`date -d '2019-10-07U'  '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'` '{print Date}'
2019-10-07T00:00:00
```

Here, I don't understand why the date `"2019-10-07T"` returns `"2019-10-07T01:00:00"` and `"2019-10-07S"` returns `"2019-10-07T02:00:00"` etc.

I have tried to get the meaning of T, S, you etc. But couldn't find any.

Could you please advice?

Comment: This has nothing to do with awk

Comment: @oguz-ismail correctly points out that you're not using `awk` to do anything other than print out exactly what it receives. You're using `date`, not `awk` to actually process the data. Anyway, are you asking why your dates have T, D, S, or U at the end, why this affects the resulting date, and what to do about it?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, I understand it's not actually related to awk but something to do with date formats.@webb Yes, exactly that's what I was looking for. Why the dates have T, D, S or U at the end affects the resulting.

Comment: @Ramgopal Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sadly completely impossible to wrap your brain around the logic which defines the almost infinite multitude of [date-input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#General-date-syntax) which the command `date` can handle. It is, however, massively impressive that they manage to do it so well! Especially when you realise the plethora of date-time formats that humanity came up with.

What you discovered is something called [military timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones), yet another form of writing date-times, but an organised one. So when you ask `date` to convert "2019-10-07S", it will assume "2019-10-07T00:00:00" in the Sierra timezone (UTC-6). Hence, your result should be "2019-10-06T18:00:00 UTC". However, you are receiving "2019-10-07T02:00:00" which is not the same. That is because `date` returns the format string in your local time-zone and it tells me that you currently have your system set to UTC+8.

We can validate this as:

```
$ TZ="Australia/Perth" date -d "2019-10-07S" "+%FT%T %z %Z"
2019-10-07T02:00:00 +0800 AWST
$ TZ="UTC-8" date -d "2019-10-07S" "+%FT%T %z %Z"
2019-10-07T02:00:00 +0800 UTC
```

**Note:** Be aware that `TZ="UTC-8"` actually means UTC+8. This notation is interpreted as a Posix timezone. (See: [U&L: Why does TZ=UTC-8 produce dates that are UTC+8?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104088/))

[image: ISO 8601 was published on 06/05/88 and most recently amended on 12/01/04.]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. This really helps. Few points though, my timezone is actually UTC+8 but "2019-10-07U" resulted me "2019-10-07T00:00:00". Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: @Ramgopal `U` Stands for Uniform TimeZone and is UTC-8. So 2019-10-07T00:00:00U is "2019-10-06T16:00:00 UTC" and the latter one is "2019-10-07T00:00:00 UTC+8" which is your TZ.

Comment: @Ramgopal I updated the link to military timezones. It was wrong before.

Comment: @Ramgopal Oh damn ... you just mentioned your TZ is UTC+8, so my explanation is a bit off. Let me fix that for you  ... as I said ... it is completely impossible to wrap your head around the input formats.

Comment: @Ramgopal If this helped you out, have a look at [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks. It really helps and it clarified my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using something like this could be smarter in awk

```
print strftime("Time = %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", systime())
```

For your initial question, probably you can read [this](https://ss64.com/bash/date.html)

Comment: Nah, this won't work with all awks. Only GAWK and MAWK have these functions afaik